# Set class for a span based on attribute name with jquery

Tags: jquery

In my code below, i'm doing menus.

What I'm trying to do is, when a user clicks a menu item, that menu items class need to get changed to 'current' and the menu item with 'current' need to get changed to 'menu'.

But I just cannot get things to work.

Ok... current gets changed to menu. i can tell by the color. But when I click the one that was changed from 'current' to 'menu', the alert wont appear.

Also, how do i set the menu class to current based on the data-feed name that was clicked? Can you see how this can be done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>PHP, jQuery search demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
.current{
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #000000;
background-color:white;
}
.menu{
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #000000;
background-color:red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dev/ajax/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $(".menunavi .menu").click(function() {

        alert ($(this).attr("data-feed"));
//Set the span with class="current" to class="menu"
        $(".menunavi .current").addClass("menu");
//Set the span with class="menu" to class="current" were data-feed = 'whatever was clicked'
        $(".menunavi .menu").addClass("current");

    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
        <div class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="menunavi">
                    <span class="current" data-feed="photos">Photos</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="watches">Watches</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="audio">Audio</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="sports">Sports</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="drinks">Drinks</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="furniture">Furniture</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="computers">Computers</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="stationary">Stationary</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="phones">Phone</span>
                    <span class="menu" data-feed="cosmetics">Cosmetics</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So for example you click watches you want to add watches as a class to the span or what do you mean?

Comment: The class of watches has to be current. The class of Photos, which is currently current has to become menu. What you've done in your reply is just right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.menu,.current').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('current').addClass('menu');
   $(this).removeClass('menu').addClass('current');    
});​
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N4Gec/2/

Comment: Wow! Nice approach. Thanks for helping. I kept getting some weird Illegal Character error. But its solved now.

Comment: $('.menu').click(function(){ I removed .current from there. Somehow even with that gone, it'll call the function when its class is changed to current. Any idea why?

Comment: the ,.current is there because it has to target the span with the class current. The function stays on the spans if it has been called even if it changes class to anything else

Comment: The function needs to be called only when class="menu" So I did: $('.menu').live('click', function() { See your fiddle. class="current" should not call the function. Please correct me if I'm wrong :)